# Trying to use 100 thread at a time.

Tags: java, multithreading

I am creating one Testing Tool which is test the performance of the Web-Services. Now i want to test performance of my tool when 100 user hit this web service.
In Current, I create one thread which heat and show me request-response details in log. But i need to create 100 threads which work parallel and show me request-response of 100 threads.
My question is how to create `100 parallel thread's`.  Here i try to create 100 thread parallel but when i run this program it will not call `run()` method.

Here is my code.

```
public class Main implements Runnable
{
int counter= 0;
 public static void main(String args[]) throws Throwable  
 {      
  Thread t[]=new Thread[100];
  for (int j=0; j<100;j++)
  {
      t[j]=new Thread();
      t[j].start();       
  }          
 }
 public void run()
 {
  try {

        System.out.println("thread "
           +Thread.currentThread().getName()+" step "+counter++);

  } 
  catch (Throwable t) { 
      t.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
}
```

Give me some hint or reference. I don't understand where i wrong.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This hasn't todo directly with your question, but based upon your environment you may consider to split those threads over multiple pcs else you may influence your result as your threads may block each other. If you have only 8 real cores you can run only 8 threads in parallel all other threads have to wait. But the time for the response is still counting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not instantiating *your* thread class - which happens to be Main.

Your class should be like:

```
public class Main extends Thread {
    int counter= 0;
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Throwable {      
        Main t[] = new Main[100];
        for (int j=0; j<100;j++) {
            t[j] = new Main();
            t[j].start();       
        }          
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName()+" step "+counter++);
        } 
        catch (Throwable t) { 
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 You are creating Threads which don't take your Runnable in the constructor so they do nothing.

Answer (score 4):

You probably meant `t[j]=new Thread(new Main())`

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to manage your threads and you can submit your Runnable as a task to this pool.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use Apache JMeter for webservices testing purpose. It already has parallel threads feature for request/response.

Anyway: 
To create new thread use constructor:

```
Thread(Runnable target)
```

As you can see, thread implements runnable, another way is just override run method.

```
public class Thread implements Runnable
```